# Error: running unit test case NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[platform]

Tags: angular, unit-testing

While running unit test case for component I am getting the following error

**NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[platform]:
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[platform]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for platform!**

```
describe('ChangesGridComponent', () => {
  let component: ChangesGridComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ChangesGridComponent>;
    beforeEach(async () => {

        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                CommonModule,
                HttpClientModule,
        
            ],
            declarations: [
                ChangesGridComponent,
            ],
            providers: [
              AppFactory,
              EndService
            ],
            schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
        }).compileComponents();
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TemplateChangesGridComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });
    it('should create component instance', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be an issue of the 2nd `beforeEach` running before the first `beforeEach` even though the first `beforeEach` is decorated with `async/await`.

Try the following changes:

```
// !! Add waitForAsync here to wait for all asynchronous tasks to
// complete before moving on.
beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
// !! Remove await from here.
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                CommonModule,
                HttpClientModule,
        
            ],
            declarations: [
                ChangesGridComponent,
            ],
            providers: [
              AppFactory,
              EndService
            ],
            schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
        }).compileComponents();
    // !! Make sure to add extra closing bracket here.
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TemplateChangesGridComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });
```